# Does a birthdate/deathdate class should be a composition or an aggregation to an individual class?

Tags: date, uml, aggregation, composition

The entity is a person.
So the entity have a birthdate and maybe already have a deathdate.
But this dates can or cannot be informed (depends of the entity and avaibility of the informations) ; so the entity might have none of those.

But I feel to do mess with the cardinality and the relation type.

How should I represent that ?

I have created an abstract class *Individual*. It leads to 2 final class : Person (identified person) or Pseudonym (anonym person).
It linked to a class Birthdate and a class Deathdate (both are generalized as a class Date).

[Birthdate]----<>[Individual] relationship is :
one *(optional)*-to-many (0..1 - 1..*)
0..1 : Because birthdate can be omitted and individual can have just one date of birth.
1..* : Because birthdate must concern at least one, but can concern severals individual.

[Deathdate]----<>[Individual] relationship is :
one *(optional)*-to-many (0..1 - 1..*)
0..1 : Because the individual isn't dead yet and can die just once.
1..* : Because deathdate must concern at least one but can concern severals individual.

But since, theoretically, everyone have a birthdate (and will have a deathdate) I was tempted by a composition. But some might prefer keep these dates secret and I wondered if composition could allow that.
Futhermore one date can correspond to severals individuals and here also I guess composition isn't possible then OR else it's me who did the confusion between Individual class and its instances (the individuals) and then Composition would be possible but not with the aforementionned cardinality.

At the moment I chose that :

```
Aggregation :
___________                 _______________
|Birthdate|0..1-----1..*< >|               |
___________                | <<Individual>>|
|Deathdate|0..1-----1..*< >|_______________|
```

But I hesitate with this one

```
Composition :
___________              _______________
|Birthdate|0..1-----1<#>|               |
___________             | <<Individual>>|
|Deathdate|0..1-----1<#>|_______________|
```

What is the right answer ? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Why have a class for that?? And why not use simple `Date` typed properties?

Comment: The Date class is to apply different date formating method on them (difference between english MM/DD/YYYY and french DD/MM/YYYY ).The Birthdate and Deathdate class was just cause I didn't want mixt them with others dates (like publications date, etc.), especially encapsulate methods that could interact with the database since this 2 dates are more datas than markers.

Comment: The formatting is applied at the presentation layer and should not be stored with the date itself. In practice DateType is usually implemented through some kind of number and a logic how to recalculate that number into the actual date. Check in Excel/LibreOffice calc how changing the format changes the way date is shown. The underlying value remains the same - you may easily check that with a function to show number representing the date (it's embedded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of issues with the approach.

First - using a class for dates is simply an overkill. Both birthdate and deathdate are attributes of a specific person and can be easily modelled as inline properties of the Individual class. Unless there is some significant reason to use something more than the good old Date DataType, keep with the standard approach.

For visibility issue, as object oriented principles say you should not expose the properties directly anyway. Rather than that you should have an operation responsible for retrieving birthdate and deathdate that will control if the date can be read or not. You may add boolean attributes that will support that, but it isn't necessary if the ability to see the dates depend on some state of the Individual or other things (e.g. "who" asks). In the former case you may also wish to still show explicitly those boolean attributes as derived ones.

If you insist on using a class for dates (e.g. as you want to have a Wikipedia-style "Born on date"/"Deceased on date" collections) you should create just one class Date and build associations to this class pretty much similar to the way you did in your second approach. In such situation, the multiplicity does not work "database style" but is a property of association itself. In particular association you have one birthdate/deathdate and one Individual. By default you will have two 1-0..1 association one for each but depending on the approach you may have much more complex approach as well.

I'll later add diagrams for more clarity.

One last remark.

Do not use `<< >>` for the class name. Those are reserved to indicate stereotypes.
If you want to indicate that Individual is abstract either show it in italics or (if your tool doesn't allow that) use `<<abstract>>` stereotype.

Comment: Date is not a predefined data type in UML.

Comment: Thanks Ister, for the explanation. I guess I tend to complicate simple things.